# writing instance methods

Tags: java, instance-methods

I'm practicing writing an instance method that converts a natural number to an integer.

I was following a tutorial online and came up with the code below.  However when I compile, it keeps adding "`this`"  The code compiles and gives me the expected output but I'm getting a few warning messages.  Is "`this.i`" the correct syntax when creating an instance method?

```
private NaturalNumber i;

public int toInt() {
    int result = 0;
    if (!(this.i.isZero())) {
        int d = this.i.divideBy10();
        result = this.i.toInt() * 10 + d;
        this.i.multiplyBy10(d);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `this` refers the current instance.

Comment: even if you don't use `this` keyword for instance variables compiler will use to put it `this` when it compiles your code.

Comment: What do you mean by "it keeps adding" - what keeps adding? If it's the IDE, then that's an IDE-specific matter... what IDE are you using?

Comment: I think it's actually a bug in Eclipse that kicks in when you have a one-letter variable name and press Ctrl-Space or something.  Short answer - either use longer variable names or don't press Ctrl-Space.

Comment: at the if statement I'm getting "Bug: Read of unwritten field result in ProgramWithIOAndStaticMethod.toInt()
 
 The program is dereferencing a field that does not seem to ever have a non-null value written to it. Unless the field is initialized via some mechanism not seen by the analysis, dereferencing this value will generate a null pointer exception.  
 
Rank: Scary (8), 
confidence: Normal"

Comment: I realize this is the current instance but I didn't know if I was using the right syntax. I am compiling using Eclipse -- what I meant by "it," sorry. I also have changed the variable name but I'm still getting the same warning.

Comment: Wow, what a great error.  You're using some kind of analysis tool that I'm not familiar with.  But what it's telling you is that you haven't written any code that assigns any value to `i`, and yet you're trying to use it is if it had a value; which is guaranteed to have bad consequences.

Comment: Gotcha.. I was not initializing `i` correctly!  I fixed this and the bug disappeared.  Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call any internal fields or methods of an object, the keyword `this`, even if not explicitly present, is implied, referring to the object itself.

More details can be found in the Java documentation, e.g. from `Oracle`:

- [Using the this Keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

So, `this.i` simply means "variable `i` in `this` object". Of course,, `i` must have a value assigned to it before invoking any of its methods like `this.i.isZero()`, otherwise a run-time error (`NullPointerException`) will occur. The IDE may also warn against such an error (e.g., `Eclipse` underlines the offending command with a jagged yellow line).

`Java` IDEs can automatically add the `this` keyword if so specified in their preferences. For example, in `Eclipse`, you can enable this feature from

- **Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Qualify all generated field accesses with 'this'**